# How to cast from const char* to a struct?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, casting

During the development of a Qt application for Embedded Linux (where improvements in performance are really welcomed), I came across the necessity to cast from a array of chars to a given struct. Till now, that was being done with the code:

```
MyStruct* const my_struct = reinterpret_cast< MyStruct* >(qbytearray.data());
```

while `data()` being a member of the Qt class `QByteArray` that transforms the byte array to a `char*`. In doing this, tough, it makes a deep copy of the data, which is not good given the extra processing. Since I want to only read the data (the struct casted will never be used to edit), the alternative method `QByteArray::constData()` is preferable, since it doesn't make a deep copy, but in contrast returns a `const char*` instead of `char*`.

The question is: how I should do the casting now? I tried to use const_cast without success.

```
MyStruct* const my_struct = const_cast< MyStruct* >(qbytearray.constData()); // compile error

const MyStruct* const my_struct = const_cast< MyStruct* >(qbytearray.constData()); // compile error
```

and `reinterpret_cast` also didn't work because "it casts away the qualifiers", which is expected. The closest way I was capable of doing this was by first casting to `char*` and later to the struct:

```
MyStruct* const my_struct = (MyStruct*)const_cast< char* >(qbytearray.constData());
```

but I get the feeling that not only this is "circle around" the problem, but also that the casting from `char*` to `MyStruct*` will ultimately sacrifice the processing improvement I was desiring.

So how do this casting correctly?

Comment: Const cast followed by reinterpret cast (or vice versa)

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const MyStruct *>(...)`?

Comment: `T * const tvar` makes a pointer to memory that can be edited, but the pointer can't ever be reassigned to point to anything else-- basically a reference. `const T * tvar` or `T const * tvar` makes a pointer that can be reassigned to point to other things, but you can't edit what it points to. `const T * const tvar` makes a pointer that can't be used to edit what it points to and can't be reassigned to point to anything else-- effectively a const reference.

Comment: @Brian that would be at least quite non-stylish, although probably working. Thanks!

Comment: @RobK Yes, I'm aware of the differences between const positions, but thanks for the comment anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `const_cast`. You are not trying to cast away `const`-ness.

```
const MyStruct* my_struct = reinterpret_cast<const MyStruct* >(qbytearray.constData());
```

Comment: Good point :D - I just wonder; what If I did want to get a non-constant my_struct after the cast? In this particular situation there is no reason for not having a const MyStruct* my_struct, but one may want to have a non-constant casted struct even if not pretending to edit it in some situations.

Comment: @Momergil Well, in that case, you could just `const_cast<>()` the `const` pointer you got from the `reinterpret_cast<>()`. However, beware that there's `const`, and there's `const`... If the memory pointed to by that address is `const` only because some level of API deemed it should be, you'll probably be ok. However, if it's `const` because it lives in a read-only memory segment or some similar reason, casting away `const` can be ... problematic. And there's generally not an easy 100% correct way to tell the difference...